# Android NestedScrollView - how to scroll a single Item from top to bottom

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have created a NestedScrollView and it has just small Image view inside of it.  I wanted this imageView to be scrollable within its container but the imageView never scrolls. if i put in multiple views or make the imageView bigger such that it surpasses the bounds of the scrollView then it starts scrolling. but i would like to use NestedScrollView on a SINGLE small item and have the user scroll the item up and down within the scrollview container.

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bikeriding" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and it renders like this:

[image]

the effect i was hoping for is that the user could touch the screen and be able to scroll the imageview from top to bottom.  how else can i achieve this ?

Comment: For that Scroll view need to be of that much height .. Why don't you try to add a Space View with some Calculated height below and above the Image view ..

Comment: Not a job for scroll view. You should write your own control that renders your image and reacts to user gestures https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale ... OR experiment with some sort of ViewPager may be the behavior it provides while user swipes will fit your bill.

Comment: The viewpager is a interesting idea